# Access to XMLHttpRequest at http://localhost:8080 from http//:localhost:3000 has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, uuidv4());
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jfif"
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};


app.use(bodyParser.json()); // application/json
app.use(multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single("image"));
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});

app.use("/feed", feedRoutes);
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(error);
  const status = error.statusCode || 500;
  const message = error.message;
  const data = error.data;
  res.status(status).json({ message: message, data: data });
});
'''
I got this error at bottom line when I add 'socket.io'
'''
mongoose
  .connect(
    "mydatabase"
  )
  .then((result) => {
    const server = app.listen(8080);

    const io = require("socket.io")(server);
    console.log('listening');
    io.on('connection', (stream) => {
       console.log('Connected');
     });
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?something' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The problem is I set the headers but still I get this error!

Comment: Need add information about environment: Version of socket.io , Express JS, NodeJS ? Comment meaning of lines of code. Show all related source code files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this will help you resolve the issue

```
const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin : 'http://localhost:4200',
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],  
  },
});
```

Note here I am using http://localhost:4200, you can specify your origin or you do something like this *.*

```
app.use(cors({
  origin : 'http://localhost:4200',
  methods: ["GET", "POST"],
}));
```

for code performance, try to use variable for the cors and pass it.
you don't need this

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});
```